# Elegant egress from `Async` actions

Tags: haskell, concurrency

Is there a simple way of cancelling an `Async a` value, such that it won't be interrupted in the middle of some critical action? I suppose I could use a semaphore inside a loop condition.

```hs
async $ whileM readSemaphore runLoopBody
```

But I'd like to know whether `async` or some other related library supports it out-of-the-box.

---

My code, as requested.

```
-- |
-- TODO | - Rename (?)
--        - Time-out
awaitResult :: String -> IO a -> IO a
awaitResult s act = do
  putStr s
  sem <- newMVar True
  a <- async $ ellipsis sem
  r <- act
  swapMVar sem False
  return r
  where
    ellipsis :: MVar Bool -> IO ()
    ellipsis sem = void $ do
      whileM (readMVar sem) $ forM [".  ", ".. ", "...", "   "] $ \dots -> do
        putStr dots
        cursorBackward 3
        threadDelay (floor $ 0.4 * second)
      -- TODO | - If the Windows console wasn't shit, I'd use a checkmark
      putStr " (" >> withPretty fgGreen "done" >> putStrLn ")"
```

Comment: I think `Control.Concurrent.Async.cancel` throws an asynchronous exception so you could use `Control.Exception.mask` with the portion you don't want to be interrupted, but this would block the thread calling `cancel` and should be used carefully.

Comment: @ryachza I'm using an `MVar` at the moment, but I'm still wondering what the 'standard' way of doing this is (if there is a such a thing).

Comment: *is such a thing

Comment: I think `mask` is designed for exactly the occasion when you have a block that you don't want interrupted if an asynchronous exception is thrown, which sounds like what you're looking for? Perhaps you could expand your code sample and indicate how you want to cancel and what you don't want interrupted? Because as it is I don't think it would be working the way you hope if I'm understanding your question.

Comment: @ryachza I'll add the code. Works fine (atleast for now).

Comment: @ryachza And no, perhaps I should have been more specific. I'm not worried about exceptions specifically. Rather, I want to be able to cancel an action, but not eg. in the middle of a loop body. I think the code snippet will clear it up.

Comment: The way `cancel` works is by throwing an exception to the thread `async` spawns. `mask` should cause that exception to "wait" (blocking the thrower) until outside the block you don't want interrupted.

Comment: I'm aware of how `cancel` works, which is why I'm not using it in my function atm.

Comment: Looking at the updated code, it doesn't seem like you're canceling or waiting for the spawned thread to complete - just setting the "stop" flag and moving on. I would probably at least add a `wait` after setting the `MVar`, but otherwise I think what you have is fine though fundamentally different from what you asked about `cancel` and interruption.

Comment: Again, maybe I should have been clearer. I'm simply looking for a way of stopping a thread at a specific point (or *not* stopping it at some other point). I used the word 'cancelling' in a generic sense. Adding `wait` is probably a good idea though (I removed it when clearing out some debug logic).

Comment: @ryachza Wanna write up an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152151/discussion-between-swiftsnamesake-and-ryachza).

Answer (score 1):

The phrasing of the question made me think of a more antagonistic relationship, in which case using `Control.Concurrent.mask` to limit when the task can be interrupted should be reasonable.

Based on the updated code it seems the threads have a tight coupling and the first alternative I can think of would be spawning the action instead of the indicator and using `poll`, which I think is less noisy than the `MVar` route:

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Control.Exception (throw)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Concurrent.Async (Async,async,poll)

second :: (Num a) => a
second = 1000000

awaitResult :: String -> IO a -> IO a
awaitResult s act = do
  putStrLn s
  a <- async $ act
  ellipsis a
  where
    ellipsis :: Async a -> IO a
    ellipsis a = do
      result <- poll a
      case result of
        Nothing -> do
          forM_ [".  ",".. ","...","   "] $ \dots -> do
            putStr dots
            putStr "\r"
            threadDelay $ floor $ 0.4 * second
          ellipsis a
        Just (Left e) -> throw e
        Just (Right x) -> return x

main = awaitResult "testing" (threadDelay (5 * second) >> return 5)
```

Comment: My question was really about the **preferred/best/most efficient/orthodox** way of interrupting a thread at a specific point. I'm *not* just looking for the nicest way of implementing `awaitResult` (which admittedly could use some polishing). As an aside, it's rather important in my particular case that the action executes in the main thread.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake I'm not sure there is one, in general. I think it would be preferred to avoid explicit `MVar` management if possible, but sometimes it is the best option. If you can present an example and/or a set of requirements I would be happy to take a look. In `awaitResult`, for example, there's the potential for a significant (depending on your definition) delay between the action completing and the result propagating.

Comment: I'll follow up tomorrow. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Sure thing. I can't during the day (firewall) but in the evening I would be happy to use chat if you'd like.